# Get aggregates from different Dataframe to current Dataframe with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a harvest dataframe and a weather dataframe.
I want to get the number of days above a temp threshold for the previous x months before harvest for all blocks.
Note the harvest dataframe includes multiple years and the id is not 1-1 between frames, ie 2 blocks in harvest df can share an ID that correspond to a location in the weather frame.

My current (working) code is below, but it is VERY slow, on the order of minutes. I want to speed it up but unclear how.

```
def days_above_thresh(x, weather_df):
    return weather_df.loc[
            (weather_df["id"]==x.id) & \
            (weather_df["day"]>=x['harvest_date']-DateOffset(months=2)) & \
            (weather_df["day"]<=x['harvest_date']) & \
            (weather_df["temperature_max"]>30),
            "temperature_max"].count()

harvest_df["days_above_30"] = harvest_df.apply(days_above_thresh , args=(weather_df,), axis=1)
```

The dataframes would look something like this -

```
weather_df
id      day      temperature_max
1    2020-01-01    30
1    2020-01-02    32
1    2020-01-03    28
1    2020-01-04    25 
         .
         .
         .
2    2020-01-01    10
2    2020-01-02    15
2    2020-01-03    17
2    2020-01-04    12
         .
         .
         .

harvest_df
id   farm_id  harvest_date
1       87    2020-01-02 
1       86    2020-01-03
2       13    2020-01-30
```

Comment: Added mock dataframes

Answer (score 1):

This could be sped up by merging the two frames on `id`, filtering the resulting frame using the boolean mask (that is constructed in the function you defined) and calling `groupby.size` on the result.

If your frames are large (but not too large), this will cut down the runtime significantly (if `harvest_df` is 10k rows, it cuts down runtime from 13.5sec to 15ms). However, if `harvest_df` is too large (maybe millions of rows), since it creates an even larger frame, you might run into memory issues.

Also, `pd.DateOffset` is not optimized for some reason; however, `np.timedelta64` is, so replacing it improves speed even further.

```py
tmp = harvest_df.reset_index().merge(weather_df[['id', 'day', 'temperature_max']], on='id', how='left')
msk = tmp['day'].between(tmp['harvest_date'].sub(np.timedelta(2, 'M')).dt.floor('D'), tmp['harvest_date']) & tmp['temperature_max'].gt(30)
harvest_df["days_above_30"] = tmp[msk].groupby('index').size().reindex(harvest_df.index, fill_value=0)
```

Could also write it as a one-liner:

```py
harvest_df["days_above_30"] = (
    harvest_df.reset_index().merge(weather_df[['id', 'day', 'temperature_max']], on='id', how='left')
    .assign(two_month_prior=lambda x: x['harvest_date'].sub(np.timedelta64(2, 'M')).dt.floor('D'))
    .query("two_month_prior <= day <= harvest_date and temperature_max > 30")
    .groupby('index').size()
    .reindex(harvest_df.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: The weather dataframe is very large (34k rows) and the harvest df is 12k rows so this would create a huge dataframe. I think it would cause memory issues.

But the alternative is very much appreciated nonetheless.

Just tried and the kernal crashes

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd 34k rows is small enough that it shouldn’t raise any problems imo.

Comment: sorry I missed a zero, the weather df is 340k rows